# Unable to send more than one message to Google Dialogflow from a website hosted on node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, dialogflow-es

I am playing around with Google Dialogflow and have setup a nodejs on an Amazon EC2 instance that connects to our Google Dialogflow instance. I basically used modified the examples from [Building a client-side web app which streams audio from a browser microphone to a server.](https://github.com/dialogflow/selfservicekiosk-audio-streaming/tree/master/examples). I am using the following Google authentication below to connect to the Dialogflow locally and via an EC2 instance.

```
> export PROJECT_ID="{PROJEC_ID}" 
> gcloud config set project $PROJECT_ID
> export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="credentials.json" 
> gcloud auth login
```

It works as expected when I run it locally on my machine. However, when I do the exact same thing on the EC2 instance it works fine for the very first query I send to the Google Dialogflow, however all subsequent calls I get the following error back.

> (node:13650) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 7
> PERMISSION_DENIED: Your application has authenticated using end user
> credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are
> not supported by the dialogflow.googleapis.com. We recommend
> configuring the billing/quota_project setting in gcloud or using a
> service account through the auth/impersonate_service_account setting.
> For more information about service accounts and how to use them in
> your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.

What baffles me, is that when I run it locally this is not an issue, and when I use the same Google authentication and example webpage on the EC2 instance; the first query gets the expected response back from the Dialogflow, but any additional queries cause the above error.

Comment: One little note. For the "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS" I did not upload the .json file instead I just copied and pasted the json information into a file saved on the EC2 instance. Not sure if this makes a different.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what the issue was. I am using sudo to launch the server on the EC2 instance, which does not access the environment variables e.g., GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. A simple flag set of sudo -E was all I needed.